# Why is this sql script so slow and how to make it lightning fast?

Tags: sql, sql-server, optimization, sql-server-2008-r2

Here is my sql script

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.calendario (
    datacal DATETIME NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    horautil BIT NOT NULL DEFAULT 1
);

-- DELETE FROM dbo.calendario;

DECLARE @dtmin DATETIME, @dtmax DATETIME, @dtnext DATETIME;

SELECT
    @dtmin = '2014-03-11 00:00:00'
    , @dtmax = '2030-12-31 23:50:00'
    , @dtnext = @dtmin;

WHILE (@dtnext <= @dtmax) BEGIN
    INSERT INTO dbo.calendario(datacal) VALUES (@dtnext);
    SET @dtnext = DATEADD(MINUTE, 10, @dtnext);
END;
```

Basically, I want to create a table with date intervals of 10 minutes each. The loop inserts a lot of records, but I thought it would be fast to execute that. It takes several minutes...

I'm using sql server 2008 r2.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Maybe introducing an explicit transaction around the loop will help.

Comment: Your example is a procedural/iterative approach.  SQL Server usually works more efficiently with a set-based approach.

Comment: I'd agree that an explicit transaction might help. But is it such a problem that this takes several minutes? This is just a one-off setup script, right? If you're running this on a regular basis on a production system, you probably need to re-think your approach.

Comment: Yes, it will be a one-off setup in production, but I'm still in development :)

Comment: Actually, adding an explicit transaction has reduced execution time from +/- 20min to just 55sec. Thanks! Can you write a response so I could accept it?

Comment: Ah, "several" as in 20 min, not 2-3. Yeah, I can see how that would get annoying. :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should avoid loops etc and try to approach this set-based. (google for "RBAR SQL")

Anyway, this runs in 1 sec on my laptop:

```
DROP TABLE dbo.calendario 
GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.calendario (
    datacal DATETIME NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    horautil BIT NOT NULL DEFAULT 1
);

-- DELETE FROM dbo.calendario;

DECLARE @dtmin DATETIME, @dtmax DATETIME, @intervals int

SELECT @dtmin = '2014-03-11 00:00:00'
     , @dtmax = '2030-12-31 23:50:00'


SELECT @intervals = DateDiff(minute, @dtmin, @dtmax) / 10

;WITH 
  L0   AS(SELECT 1 AS c UNION ALL SELECT 1),
  L1   AS(SELECT 1 AS c FROM L0 AS A, L0 AS B),
  L2   AS(SELECT 1 AS c FROM L1 AS A, L1 AS B),
  L3   AS(SELECT 1 AS c FROM L2 AS A, L2 AS B),
  L4   AS(SELECT 1 AS c FROM L3 AS A, L3 AS B),
  L5   AS(SELECT 1 AS c FROM L4 AS A, L4 AS B),
  L6   AS(SELECT 1 AS c FROM L5 AS A, L5 AS B),
  Nums AS(SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY c) AS n FROM L6)

INSERT INTO dbo.calendario(datacal)
SELECT DateAdd(minute, 10 * (n - 1), @dtmin)
  FROM Nums
 WHERE n BETWEEN 1 AND @intervals + 1

-- SELECT * FROM dbo.calendario ORDER BY datacal
```

Comment: That's why I love stackoverflow. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This code takes 23 seconds on my machine (and most of it in sorting)

```
DECLARE @DateMin AS datetime = '2014-03-11 00:00:00';
DECLARE @DateMax AS datetime = '2030-12-31 23:50:00';

DECLARE @Test AS Table (
   datacal DATETIME NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
);

WITH Counter AS (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY a.object_id) -1 AS Count
    FROM sys.all_objects AS a
         CROSS JOIN sys.all_objects AS b
)
INSERT INTO @Test (datacal)
SELECT DATEADD(minute, 10 * Count, @DateMin)
FROM Counter
WHERE DATEADD(minute, 10 * Count, @DateMin) <= @DateMax
```

Answer (score 1):

Some interesting answers already.  Here is another set-based option that also uses common table expressions.

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME = '2014-03-11 00:00:00';
DECLARE @EndDate DATETIME = '2030-12-31 00:00:00';

--CTE of days in the Start/End date range.
WITH DaysTable AS
(
    SELECT @StartDate AS CalendarDate
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(dd, 1, CalendarDate)
    FROM DaysTable
    WHERE CalendarDate < @EndDate
) 
--CTE of 10 min intervals for one day.
,MinsTable AS
(
    SELECT CAST(0 AS DATETIME) MinutesDate
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(MINUTE, 10, mt.MinutesDate)
    FROM MinsTable mt
    WHERE MinutesDate < DATEADD(MINUTE, -10, CAST(0 AS DATETIME) + 1)
) 
SELECT DATEADD(MINUTE, DATEDIFF(MINUTE, CAST(0 AS DATETIME), mt.MinutesDate), dt.CalendarDate) Every10Min
INTO #TestTable
FROM MinsTable mt
--Cross join for all 10 min intervals of all days in date range.
CROSS JOIN DaysTable dt
ORDER BY DATEADD(MINUTE, DATEDIFF(MINUTE, CAST(0 AS DATETIME), mt.MinutesDate), dt.CalendarDate)
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 32767)

SELECT *
FROM #TestTable
```